# Angular 5 + NodeJS+ MongoDB - How to implement voice/speech recording and playback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular

I am creating an Angular 5 application, with a nodejs and mongodb backend.

A feature needs to be implemented to allow a user to record their speech on a page. Later the speech will need to be played back on a different page, therefore it should be saved.

1. What can i use to record a users voice via their microphone in the browser?.
2. How do i store this recording? e.g in a mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

I developed the same functionality half year ago. Except it was .NET on the backend and Angular 1.x on the frontend. I've used `getUserMedia` on the client with the help of the following articles:

http://typedarray.org/from-microphone-to-wav-with-getusermedia-and-web-audio/

http://typedarray.org/from-microphone-to-wav-to-server/

There's big chunks of code which you will need to adopt for your specific case. 
In general I'd suggest to `getUserMedia` on the client, then convert in to `wav` on the client and upload this `Blob` to the server. Then you can save this file on the server and store path to it in MongoDB. I believe this will be the most efficient way. Another option will be to convert this `wav` to base64 and store in DB as string, but it's not the best idea, since this will be dramatically big string.